# Prove or disprove the convergence of integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

There is an integral
$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{cos^3 ( \ln x)}{x\ln x}dx$$

Prove or disprove its convergence/absolute converegence.

Initially I thought about Taylor series expansion at $x \to 0+$ for $\ln x$, but I get really bad values for $\cos$ function like $-1, -2, \dotso$ and so on.

Comment: Hint: maybe let $u = \ln x$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson So, the $1/2$ becomes $\sqrt{e}$, right?

Comment: No, because $u(1/2) = -\ln 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**
With $t=1/x =e^u$, the integral has the same nature than

$$-\int_2^{+\infty}\frac {cos^3 (\ln (t))}{t\ln (t)}dt $$
and
$$-\int_{\ln (2)}^{+\infty}\frac {\cos^3 (u)}{u}du.$$

As said above, linearise $cos^3$ and use Abel's rule near $+\infty $ or a by parts integration.

Answer (score 1):

like Sean Roberson said I think you should let $u=\ln(x)$. Then you will get $\cos^3(u)/u$ in the integrand. Then you can use the trig identity: 
$\cos^3(x) =(\cos(3x)+3\cos(x))/4$. So now you have essentially a bunch of integrals of $\cos(u)/u$ from $-\infty$ to $-\ln(2)$ which are simpler to integrate.

Comment: Why $\frac{\cos u}{u}$? I think it should be $\frac{\cos u}{e^uu}$...

Comment: $x = e^u$ gives $dx = e^u \, du$ so $e^u$ cancels out.